# How to fixed space between bars on chart.js?

Tags: html, css, chart.js

[image]

How to fix these spacing between bars ? when i have few data its become long width spacing.

What i want is

1. fixed bar size
2. fixed spacing between bars
3. fit-content of canvas width so when there just a few data, its become compact and if its have much data , its become long

Note: My chart.js version is 4.4.0

Comment: Thank you for all your respond , but i found what i need in this video, i will close this question, thanks all

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV6Qy5EQZlA

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the spacing between bars in a chart created with Chart.js, you generally have to tweak a few configuration options related to the chart's scales and dataset. The spacing can be influenced by the barThickness, categoryPercentage, and barPercentage properties.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the demo of this sample chart as it will be similar in your code I am guessing.

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

```
var data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sample Data',
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
};

var options = {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10
        }
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        y: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            },
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
        }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

And now your requirements will fit in as per three things below:

- layout.padding is set to add some padding around the chart area.
- scales.x.grid.display and scales.y.grid.display are set to false to
  hide the grid lines.
- maintainAspectRatio is set to false to allow the chart to adjust its
  size based on the container width.

Hope this helps. Let me know how it goes.